# Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear map such that $T^3 = T$. Show that $T$ is diagonalizable (elementarily)

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

While revising for my linear algebra exam I came across this exam problem:

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear mapping such that $T^3 = T$ and $T^2 \neq T,T^2 \neq \text{id}_V$.

If $ \text{dim(ker(} T )) = 2$, show that the matrix of $T$ is equal to diag$(0,0,-1)$ with respect to a suitable basis.

**My idea**

Assume for the moment that $T$ is diagonalizable. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ then $\lambda^3 = \lambda$ since $T^3 = T$, so $\lambda \in \{ 0,-1,1 \}$.

Since $ \text{dim(ker(} T )) = 2$, clearly $0$ is an eigenvalue. If all three values above would be eigenvalues then the geometric multiplicity of $0$ would be $1$ and not $2$, so $-1$ and $1$ can't both be eigenvalues.

If $1$ is the other eigenvalue then since $T$ is diagonalizable we'd have that the matrix of $T$ is $M = $ diag $(0,0,1)$ with respect to some basis. But $M^2 = M$ so we'd have $T^2 = T$ which is not the case.

So $-1$ must be the other eigenvalue and the result follows.

**Question** How can I prove that $T$ is diagonalizable? For some context, the only definition of diagonalizability we have is that $T: V \rightarrow V$ diagonalizable if there is a basis of $V$ made up of eigenvectors of $V$ and that's how we usually prove diagonalizability (by explicitely providing a basis). We also have the spectral theorem for symmetric matrices but I doubt it helps here.

(I also know that the minimal polynomial of $T$ must divide $x(x-1)(x+1)$ via the relation given, so the minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors, so $T$ is definitely diagonalizable. But we haven't done this in the course and this method wouldn't be accepted in the exam without a full proof, so I'm looking for a more elementary way.)

Comment: You don't need to assume that $T$ is diagonalizable. Simply consider $T(T-1)(T+1)=0$. It is obviously the characteristic polynomial of $T$, hence $T$ has three different eigevalues.

Comment: @MariusS.L.: If the geometric multiplicity of $0$ is $2$ then there isn't room for both $-1$ and $1$ to be eigenvalues. So $T$ distinctly _doesn't_ have three different eigenvalues.

Comment: @Troposphere You are right. One has to discuss the cases $T(T-1)\, , \,T(T+1)\, , \,T^2-1.$ All other combinations are already diagonal or diagonalizable.

Comment: @Tanny: Do you have the Jordan canonical form available?

Comment: @Troposphere Sadly no. Basically the only thing which works under the curriculum is to show that $\text{dim(ker}(T+I)) = 1$ (or that $-1$ is in fact an eigenvalue). This seems easy but I just couldn't find a way to show it.

Comment: Look at https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/115a.3.02f/week8.pdf page 8 and 9, if the characterisitic polynomial has all distinct roots of multiplicity $1$, then the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: @zwim but the characteristic polynomial here does not have all distinct roots. The function that $T$ satisfies here is not the characteristic polynomial of $T$. (see Troposphere's comments above)

Comment: if it were me, I'd start with $\text{rank}\big(T\big)=\text{rank}\big(T^3\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(T^2\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(T\big)\implies \text{rank}\big(T^2\big)= \text{rank}\big(T\big)$ $\implies V = \text{im }\big(T\big)\oplus \ker \big(T\big)$ and then divide and conquer.  Building a basis for the kernel is easy; when restricted to the subspace $\text{im }\big(T\big)$, then $T$ is invertible so it satisfies $T^2 =I$ which is an involution, which is always diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\pm 1$ (technical nit: so long as the field doesn't have characteristic 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $T^3=T$ we obtain $T(T+1)(T-I)v=0$ for any $v$, so

$(T^2-I)v=v_0$ is an eigenvector $v_0$ of $\lambda = 0$

$(T^2+T)v=v_1$ is an eigenvector $v_1$ of $\lambda= 1$

$(T^2-T)v=v_{-1}$ is an eigenvector $v_{-1}$ of $\lambda=-1$

(why)?

But, in that case,

$$v=\frac{1}{2}v_1 + \frac{1}{2}v_{-1} - v_0$$

Can you conclude?

Comment: Oh! So ker($T$) + ker($T + I$) + ker($T - I$) = $\mathbb{R^3}$, so we can definitely extract a basis of $\mathbb{R^3}$ made from eigenvectors of $T$, so $T$ is diagonalizable, right?

Answer (score 4):

Very elementarily:

Choose a basis for the kernel of $T$ and extend to a basis for the entire $\mathbb R^3$. The matrix of $T$ in this basis is now
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 & c \end{pmatrix} $$
and then by direct computation
$$ T^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & ca \\ 0 & 0 & cb \\ 0 & 0 & c^2 \end{pmatrix} 
\qquad
T^3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & c^2a \\ 0 & 0 & c^2b \\ 0 & 0 & c^3 \end{pmatrix} $$
Since $T^3=T$ we must have $c^3=c$, but $c\ne 1$ because $T^2\ne T$, and $c\ne 0$ because otherwise $T=T^3=0$ whose kernel is too large. Therefore $c=-1$.

This means that $-1$ is an eigenvalue, and you can replace the third basis vector by a corresponding eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(v_1, v_2)$ be a basis of $\ker T$ and let $\text{im }T = \text{span } v_3  \ne 0$

It is clear that $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ is an eigenbasis...

For otherwise $v_3 \in \ker T$ so $T^2 = 0$. Thus $T = T^3 = 0$,  contradiction.

Comment: I don't think the two alternatives for $v_3$ are either it is an eigenvector, or $v_3$ is in the kernel. Maybe $T$ maps $(0,0,1)$ to $(0,1,1)$?

Comment: @E-A If $v_3 \notin \ker T$ then $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ is independent and thus a basis. Since im $T =$  span $v_3$, $Tv_3 = cv_3$, so $v_3$ is an eigenvector...

Comment: That second sentence is not necessarily true; take $v_i = e_i$, and let $T(e_3) = (0,1,1)$. Then, the image of $T$ is indeed the span of $v_3$, but $T v_3$ is not equal to $c v_3$.

Comment: @E-A You say that $v_3 = e_3$ which means the image is of the form $(0,0,c)$. But then try to map $e_3$ to $(0,1,1)$... The image is spanned by one vector

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clarifying; +1